# Complex manifolds vs Riemann domains

Tags: riemann-surfaces, several-complex-variables, complex-manifolds

In Hörmander's text an "Introduction to Several Complex Variables," he gives the following definition for a Riemann domain on page 139:

A complex manifold $\Omega$ of dimension $n$ is called a Riemann domain if analytic functions separate points on $\Omega$ and there is an analytic map
\begin{equation*}
 \varphi : \Omega \to \mathbb{C}^n
\end{equation*}
which is everywhere regular, that is, locally an isomorphism.

Edit: many authors drop the word analytic and only say $\varphi$ need be a local homeomorphism.

I understand the condition concerning separating points but what I don't understand is why this second condition ($\varphi$ locally an isomorphism) is needed on top of the usual complex manifold definition. Why can we not just patch together the homeomorphisms given from the definition of a complex manifold using a partition of unity and take that as our $\varphi$? In other words, what are we trying to convey that doesn't come from the usual definition of a complex manifold?

In a similar vein, for a Riemann surface, why is such a condition not necessary? We merely define them as one-dimensional complex manifolds without stating that there need exist such a $\varphi$.

Comment: Try it and see how hard this actually is: You will end up with a multivalued function. It is a nontrivial theorem that each open Riemann surface is a Riemann domain.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257133/does-every-riemann-surface-with-boundary-immerse-in-c